# Ruby markup parser for custom markup language

Tags: ruby, parsing, markup

I am looking for a Ruby markup parser (or helper) to convert a custom markup language to HTML.
Something like [Decoda](http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/decoda) does in the PHP world (see $code->addMarkup() function). Is there a good tool in the Ruby world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy to be educated otherwise, but I'm afraid I don't think such a thing exists - someone would have had to have needed a parser (or parser-generator, perhaps) for multiple unspecified future markup languages. Probably not a need that's been experienced very often. Or ever.

However, if your language is fairly regular, I don't see that it's going to be too much more of a task to build your own parser using tools that *are* available.

Some places you might start:

- [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/)
- [Dhaka](http://dhaka.rubyforge.org/)
- [Racc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/racc/rdoc/index.html) (distributed in the Ruby standard library)

Answer (score 0):

redcloth for textile http://redcloth.org/

bluecloth for markdown http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth

personally, i like textile.

Comment: As I wrote ... I am more looking for helpers parsing my own custom markup.

Comment: sorry to mislead, that is not what i got out of the first paragraph on the Deocda page.